# Unable to Weblogic Struct Type to Oracle Struct Type

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic

i am calling a stored procedure from java and as an out parameter i am giving a `struct`. Every thing works fine with below code;

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,"username","password")
StructDescriptor recDescriptor =  StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("TCS_CHALLAN",conn);
CallableStatement stmt =  conn.prepareCall("{ call xx_get_challan_info(?, ?) }");
Object[] return_record_array = new Object[8];
STRUCT output_oracle_record;
stmt.setObject(1, challan_no);
stmt.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.STRUCT, "TCS_CHALLAN");
output_oracle_record = ((OracleCallableStatement)stmt).getSTRUCT(2);
return_record_array = output_oracle_record.getAttributes();
```

The problem occurs when i get my connection from a `datasource` at `weblogic server`.

```
javax.naming.Context initialContext = new javax.naming.InitialContext();
javax.sql.DataSource dataSource = (javax.sql.DataSource)initialContext.lookup("jdbc/testApps");
conn = dataSource.getConnection();
```

With above `conn` object when i try the same code i get an error

```
weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Struct_oracle_sql_STRUCT cannot be cast to oracle.sql.STRUCT
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I am facing a similar issue when trying to create a Struct using a WebLogic connection

Comment: @semiColon yes, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this was the solution.When running your code in weblogic you need to do some extra casting. make sure to include jar files in your classpath.

```
/*Code to support Weblogic datatypes*/
  Object returnObj = stmt.getObject(2);
  if (returnObj instanceof Struct)
                output_oracle_record = (oracle.sql.STRUCT)(((weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Struct)returnObj).unwrap(Class.forName("oracle.sql.STRUCT")));
            else
                output_oracle_record = (oracle.sql.STRUCT)returnObj;

            /*code for tomcat deployment*/
            //output_oracle_record = ((OracleCallableStatement)stmt).getSTRUCT(2);
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this. If I understand correctly, you are effectively stripping the object of its weblogic wrapper? I think the ideal solution would be to keep the wrapper and find some other way of working with the object as unwrapping the object means that weblogic can no longer monitor it for connection leaks or metrics.

Comment: I was a bit hasty, in case you aren't please let me know of the proper solution :)

Comment: I managed to get around this problem by finding another way of accomplishing my task without using Structs. So it is still a mystery to me!

Answer (score 0):

2 possible solutions :

1. Use java.sql.Struct instead of oracle.sql.STRUCT
2. Cast the connection :

> javax.naming.Context initialContext = new javax.naming.InitialContext();
>   javax.sql.DataSource dataSource = (javax.sql.DataSource)initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/MyDS");
>   con = dataSource.getConnection();
>   vendorConnection = (oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection)((weblogic.jdbc.extensions.WLConnection)con).getVendorConnection();